# extjs grid ListFilter scroll handles (ListFilter overflow)

Tags: list, extjs, filter, extjs4

I have a grid with a ListFilter on one of the columns. The list of filter items is long enough that it overflows the height the pages. However I do not get scroll handles on the list like I do with the column menu.

To illustrate this:

Column menu comes standard with top and bottom scroll handles on overflow, top handle shown here:

[image]

The ListFilter menu has no scroll handle on overflow (though it will scroll with mouse wheel):

[image]

Initially, I thought this was happening because my ListFilter implementation was based off a remote data store rather than a fixed list of options (the data isn't loaded before the grid renders). I changed to a fixed list and I still dont have any handles. Has anyone implemented scroll handles on these filter lists?

Comment: When Geronimo asks a question - you know it's going to be a good one :)

Comment: Thanks @DmitryB, hopefully that doesn't mean everyone is stumped... I left this question fermenting here while I moved on with high hopes of having solution before I finished. Half my users don't have mousewheels and most of the ones that do wouldn't know to roll it over the menu to scroll it :(

Comment: ouch! And half of them use IE6? :)  I feel for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this.self.xtype='menu'; to the constructor function inside ListMenu.js and it should work.